# Flutter Web - File doesn't update when edited externally

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a simple Flutter app with a config folder.
Does someone know how to reload a text file during the runtime?
Every time I open the debug or run the app, if I edit the text file externally it won't update, if I restart the app it will update. How can I make the file content update during runtime, automatically?

The following code is set on a timer in order to make it reread the file during a period of time, but the file isn't updating if edited externally.

```
Future<List<String>> ReadFromFile() async {

    final data = await s.rootBundle.loadString('../../config.yml');

    final mapData = loadYaml(data);
    var test = json.encode(data);
    var test2 = json.decode(test);

    List<String> rawString = test2.split('\n');
    return rawString;
  }
```

Also, this is my pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  yaml: ^3.1.0
...
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - "../../config.yml"
```

Please note that this is a Flutter Web project and might not work using solutions for smartphones.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I've been searching for.
Just use an HttpRequest like this:

It works for every file!

```
var path = '../../config.yml';

HttpRequest.getString(path).then((String fileContents) {
      print(fileContents.characters);
   }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
});
```

Also the library is `dart:html`.
Use it instead of `dart:io` if you have it.

Edit: The new settings in the file, only updates if the new file generated by Flutter (inside the Flutter project folder) is modified, not the original one. But it still works for me. Better than nothing.

Good luck everyone :D